# how to store a road with multiple routes?

Tags: postgis, linestring, st-distance, multiline

I assume everybody knows google maps. When you get any direction to you destination there is always mutliple options. Let's say I want to store such a geometry in PostGIS? What is the best approach to store geometry of a road with multiple branches? MultiLineString? Can I then calcupate distance from the "start" for every branch?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I would store each option separately with an attribute for différenciation (like Shortest/Fastest or Option1/Option2...)

Comment: would look into pgrouting https://pgrouting.org/

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the geometry of the road with the routing graph that would allow you to calculate routes between two locations.

The geometry (points, linestrings, polygons etc) define the physical location of the road (lat/lon, projection, length, width). This information does not contain any routing information. The geometry does not know which roads are connected and the rules that would connect A > B > C.

To do that you need to have a graph network that would contain information that would connect A, B and C to their neighbours and to have some kind of cost for traversing between the nodes. As @Mapperz said, take a look at [PGrouting](https://pgrouting.org/) since that allows you to store nodes, vertices and costs inside a PostGIS enabled DB.